# Expected number o f draws with replacement to reach probability.

Tags: probability

I have a bag of n red marbles, I draw randomly from this bag and replace with a blue marble from a bottomless bag of blue marbles. How do I determine the expected probability of drawing a blue marble after m draws?

Comment: Either you ask "what is the probability of drawing a blue marble after $m$ draws?" or you ask "what is the expected number of draws before drawing a blue marble?". In its current state, your question is rather confusing (the title is meaningless, and the term "expected probability" is kind of enigmatic).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try to be more clear in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that your marbles stay fixed over time, though they change their color to blue if you select them.  It follows that the probability that the marble you select is red is $\left( \frac {n-1}n\right)^{m-1}$ (as the only way it can be red is if you never picked it in any prior draw).  The probability that it is blue is therefore $$1-\left( \frac {n-1}n\right)^{m-1}$$